# no operators and parenthesis in output of Infix To Postfix

Tags: c++, infix-notation, postfix-notation

Here i have a code for converting Infix To Postfix using Stack

the code compiled without errors but my problem is When I enter any infix e.g A+B i got a postfix of AB without the operators or parenthesis i couldn't solve this problem and i have an exam tomorrow please save me and tell me What i am missing here and thanks a lot.....

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
struct stack
{
int ptr;
char arr[50];
stack()
{
    ptr=0;
}
char top()
{
    return arr[ptr];
}
void push(char ch)
{
    ptr++;
    arr[ptr]=ch;
}
void pop()
{

    ptr-- ;

}
};
void Convert(char[50],char[50]);
bool IsOperand(char);
    bool TakesPrecedence(char,char);
void main()
{
char Reply;
do 
{
    char Infix[50],Postfix[50]="";
    cout<<"Enter an Infix expression: "<<endl;
    cin>>Infix;

    Convert(Infix,Postfix);
    cout<<"The equivalent postfix expression is: "<<endl<<Postfix<<endl;

    cout<<endl<<"Do another (y/n)? ";
    cin>>Reply;

}
while (Reply =='y');
}
void Convert(char Infix[50],char Postfix[50])
{
stack OperatorStack;
char TopSymbol,Symbol;
int L;
for(unsigned k=0;k<strlen(Infix);k++)
{
    Symbol=Infix[k];
    if (IsOperand(Symbol))
    {
        L=strlen(Postfix);
        Postfix[L]=Symbol;
        Postfix[L+1]='\0';

    }
    else
    {
        while ( OperatorStack.ptr && TakesPrecedence(OperatorStack.top(),Symbol))
        {
            TopSymbol= OperatorStack.top();
            OperatorStack.pop();
            L=strlen(Postfix);
            Postfix[L]=TopSymbol;
            Postfix[L+1]='\0';
        }
        if( OperatorStack.ptr && Symbol==')')
            OperatorStack.pop();
        else 
            OperatorStack.push(Symbol);
    }
}
while(OperatorStack.ptr)
{
    TopSymbol=OperatorStack.top();
    OperatorStack.pop();
    L=strlen(Postfix);
    Postfix[L+1]='\0';
}
}
bool IsOperand(char ch)
{
if((ch >='a' &&ch <= 'z') ||(ch >='A' &&ch <= 'Z')||(ch >='0' &&ch <= '9'))
    return true;
else 
    return false;
}
bool TakesPrecedence(char OperatorA,char OperatorB)
{
if(OperatorA='(')
    return false;
else if(OperatorB='(')
    return false;
else if(OperatorB=')')
    return true;
else if(OperatorA='^' && (OperatorB='^'))
    return false;
else if(OperatorA='^')
    return true;
else if(OperatorB='^')
    return false;
else if(OperatorA='*' || (OperatorA='/'))
    return true;
else if(OperatorB='*' || (OperatorB='/'))
    return false;
else
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure

```
if(OperatorA='(')
```

and all other should be

```
if(OperatorA=='(')
```

But my main advice is for you to start using a debugger. This could have easily been spotted during debugging. I can't stress enough how important knowing how to debug is.

Comment: thanks a lot for your fast reply 

after correcting this i tried a+b*c-d and the Postfix output is abc*+d not abc*+d-

what am i doing wrong this time ?